# Attached file is empty

Tags: powershell

I am trying to attach the results of a SQL query to an email but the attached file only has the full path of the file inside the excel. (C:temp\ertasdfdrt\filename.csv) etc.   Is there a way to write the actual content to the attachment? The Export works properly since I see it when I store it locally.  This is being done in the cloud so I don't want to write it to a local directory.

```
$attachment = New-Item file.csv -ItemType file
$DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-CSV $attachment -NoTypeInformation 
---
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage($from, $to, $subject, $emailbody)
$att = [System.Net.Mail.Attachment]::CreateAttachmentFromString($attachment, $attachment.Name)
$msg.Attachments.Add($att)
```

Comment: why do you expect that static method to do anything other than what it did? the MSDocs say `Creates a mail attachment using the content from the specified string`. there is nothing at all there about the content of the FILE that the string points to. [*grin*]

Comment: Would CreateAttachmentFromString() turn it into an attachment?

$att = [System.Net.Mail.Attachment]::CreateAttachmentFromString($attachment)

Comment: i don't know. [*blush*] i have no need for sending email via PoSh, so i haven't ever tried it. the builtin `Send-MailMessage` seems to do what you need ... why don't you use that instead of fighting with the dotnet stuff? [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

`$attachment` is a pointer to the 'file.csv' that was created. `CreateAttachmentFromString` does as it's name suggests and creates an attachment using the parameter passed in as the content of the attachment. In this case, `$attachment` is evaluating to the file name instead of the file content so that is what is used for the attachment content.

I would suggest something like this:

```
$attachment = ($DataSet.Tables[0] | ConvertTo-CSV)
---
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage($from, $to, $subject, $emailbody)
$att = [System.Net.Mail.Attachment]::CreateAttachmentFromString($attachment, "file.csv")
$msg.Attachments.Add($att)
```

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.attachment.createattachmentfromstring?view=netframework-4.8) for more details of how to use `CreateAttachmentFromString`

Or just replace the `CreateAttachmentFromString' with the Attachment constuctor

```
$attachment = New-Item file.csv -ItemType file
$DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-CSV $attachment -NoTypeInformation 
---
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage($from, $to, $subject, $emailbody)
$att = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($attachment)
$msg.Attachments.Add($att)
```

Or switch to the Powershell Send-MailMessage cmdlet.